# "The ( kind/type ) of stress those activities tend to (cause/give/provoke/other) ...". Which noun and verb should I use?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs, nouns

In this context:

> *"The **kind/type** of stress those activities tend to **(verb)**..."*

- I've found that **kind** / **type** are used interchangeably, is one more appropiate than the other?
- Talking about the verb, I've found very few examples of sentences like "X gives/causes me stress", so I'm not sure if I could use one of them here or if there's another more suitable verb.

So: **Which noun (kind/type) and verb (give/cause/provoke/other) would be appropiate for this sentence?**

Comment: [The kind/type of stress those activities tend to (verb)] is just a noun phrase, not a sentence. Seeing you wrote *The* I guess that you're going to begin your sentence with this noun phrase, which is strange for me. Perhaps because it's too heavy. Let's consider it as just a noun phrase, without it being at the beginning of a sentence. In my opinion, either *kind* or *type* is fine. As for the verb, I personally tend to use simple words, so I think *cause* or *induce* is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that it's just a noun phrase, although by the "..." I pretended to show it's going to be in a sentece, I could have expressed myself better. Anyway by the time I wrote it, I hadn't actually noticed it was just a noun phrase, so double thanks. I don't have a clear "sense of weight" when making sentences, so it's possible that I made it sound a bit strange. Do you know  if that concept is searchable under an specific title or if it's just an ability adquired by being familiar with the language usage?.

Comment: I can only offer these two tips at the moment: 1) generally in English, more important things comes last (we can apply this concept not only to sentences, but also, for example, punchlines, conclusions, wrap-ups, etc.), 2) reading what you just wrote aloud helps (presumably, we've read lots of books, documents, etc. before we write our own stuff; reading aloud could help telling us whether our sentences have good balance or not). I believe that there are more resources on writing out there; I just don't know where myself, though. :)

Comment: Particularly in "medical" contexts, we often say [*stress is **triggered** by {something}*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stress+triggered+by%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say:

> The **kind** of stress those activities tend to **cause**...

using *kind* for undefined or loosly defined cases. To the average person, stress is probably a loosely defined condition.

> What **kind** of lunch are you having?

since there are more variations of food items than you would have in mind.

I would use *type* when referring clearly defined cases.
For example, if I was a psychologist, I might say:

> The **type** of stress those activities tend to **cause**...

because I would know specific types of stress one may experience.
*type* is also used to describe specific conditions, like:

> What **type** of diabetes do you have?
>   I have **type** 2 diabetes.

Finally, in the above examples I would use *cause* for the verb, as this phrase describes a cause and effect relationship.